# QTP Using Public Functions - Set file path in Test

Tags: qtp, hp-uft

So I am using a public function that scans text documents. Because I am going to be scanning through multiple documents, I want to define the actual file path and file name in the test itself, and call the public function.

Here is what I have setup:

```
Public Function TextFind

    Dim fso, textFile, rgxp, Regexp, contents, matches,VariableFilePath

    Const ForReading = 1
    Set fso = CreateObject( "Scripting.FileSystemObject" )
    Set textFile = fso.OpenTextFile(VariableFilePath(), ForReading )
    contents = textFile.ReadAll
    textFile.Close

    Set rgxp = New Regexp
    rgxp.Pattern = chr(34) & "Test Testing Tested" & chr(34)
    rgxp.IgnoreCase = False
    rgxp.Global = True
    Set matches = rgxp.Execute( contents )
    If matches.Count = 500 Then
        Print "Test Testing Tested: " & matches.Count
    End If

End Function
```

Here is the call I am attempting to make:

```
Option Explicit

Dim VariableFilePath
VariableFilePath = "C:\Users\ME\Documents\Testing\G1.txt"

Call TextFind
```

When I make the call, I am getting an error about type mismatch with VariableFilePath in the Public Function Library. How do I fix this? Note: using QTP 11.0.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly change this:

```
Set textFile = fso.OpenTextFile(VariableFilePath(), ForReading )
```

To :

```
Set textFile = fso.OpenTextFile(VariableFilePath, ForReading )
```

VariableFilePath is string - not a function. And pass VariableFilePath as parameter to TextFind.

Edit: Throw away VariableFilePath declaration in TextFind function

Hmm... Public function without class?

Comment: I removed the VariableFilePath declration from the Public Function TextFind and removed the () from the set file line. When I attempt to run the call, I get the error:

Variable is undefined: 'VariableFilePath'.

How would I pass the file location as parameter to TextFind function?

Comment: `Function TextFind(parameterName)  
function content  
...  
Set textFile = fso.OpenTextFile(parameterName, ForReading )  
End Function`

Comment: >>Hmm... Public function without class?<< What´s wrong with global public functions?

Comment: I'm just used to that public or private scope are connected with OOP concepts, not with structural scripting.